# Unwanted bars in nodes of manifest variables by semPlot::semPaths

Tags: r, r-lavaan, semplot

I am using the following code `semPlot::semPaths` to plot a `lavaan` model (the complete reproducible code is [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/psyguy/1a3eed7ce19fedec0b45d12543469e74)).

```r
semPaths(f,
         title = FALSE,
         curvePivot = TRUE,
         what = "std",
         rotation = 2,
         layout = "tree2",
         optimizeLatRes = TRUE,
         intercepts = FALSE,
         edge.label.cex = 0.95,
         exoVar=FALSE,
         sizeMan=5,
         sizeLat=7,
         nCharNodes=5,
         residuals=FALSE,
         fixedStyle=1,
         freeStyle=1,
         curvePivot = FALSE)
```

And the following is the `semPaths` output:

[image]

As you can see, there are weired horizonla lines in the last four manifest variables. How can I remove them? (and why it's happening?)

Thanks in advance!

#### Update:

This is also the case if saved to PDF (by adding arguments `filetype = "pdf", filename = "x"`) to the function:

[image: filename = "x"]

Comment: how about adding `thresholds = FALSE` to your `semPaths` function?

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that solved it! But I'm curious how that argument bein TRUE had made the issue?

Comment: if `TRUE` (default) then thresholds included in path diagram; default for `threshAtSide` is `FALSE` which puts the small lines inside of nodes

Comment: Ah I see, didn't see how `threshold` related to the threshold parameters estimated by lavaan. Thanks.